# How to connect cassandra with sailsjs

Tags: cassandra, sails.js

We are using 2 different servers for Cassandra and sailsjs. All the modules are configured in sailsjs. we are trying to run sails lift but getting the below error code :

info: Starting app...

/doowdle/backend/node_modules/cassandra-store/lib/CassandraStore.js:45
                    throw error;
                    ^
Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, X.X.X.X:9042: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED X.X.X.X:9042. See innerErrors.

Is there anything that i missed in cassandra.yaml file?

When I run ./cassandra, i got the following output:

owner@STS-YYC-UBUNTU:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/bin$ ./cassandra
owner@STS-YYC-UBUNTU:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.2.12/bin$ CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell.compareTo (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/composites/AbstractSimpleCellNameType.compareUnsigned (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [credentials_validity_in_ms, enable_scripted_user_defined_functions, column_index_cache_size_in_kb, back_pressure_enabled, enable_materialized_views, cdc_enabled, prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, back_pressure_strategy, concurrent_materialized_view_writes, transparent_data_encryption_options, thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms, hints_flush_period_in_ms, max_hints_file_size_in_mb] from your cassandra.yaml
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [credentials_validity_in_ms, enable_scripted_user_defined_functions, column_index_cache_size_in_kb, back_pressure_enabled, enable_materialized_views, cdc_enabled, prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, back_pressure_strategy, concurrent_materialized_view_writes, transparent_data_encryption_options, thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms, hints_flush_period_in_ms, max_hints_file_size_in_mb] from your cassandra.yaml
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader$MissingPropertiesChecker.check(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:113)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:149)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:133)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:507)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642)
ERROR 03:26:04 Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [credentials_validity_in_ms, enable_scripted_user_defined_functions, column_index_cache_size_in_kb, back_pressure_enabled, enable_materialized_views, cdc_enabled, prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, back_pressure_strategy, concurrent_materialized_view_writes, transparent_data_encryption_options, thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms, hints_flush_period_in_ms, max_hints_file_size_in_mb] from your cassandra.yaml
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader$MissingPropertiesChecker.check(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:113) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:149) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:507) [apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642) [apache-cassandra-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a cassandra.yaml file from cassandra 3.x, with an install on cassandra 2.2.12. So the new options listed in the error message:

> 03:26:04 Exception encountered during startup
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml.
>   Please remove properties [**credentials_validity_in_ms**,
>   **enable_scripted_user_defined_functions**, **column_index_cache_size_in_kb**,
>   **back_pressure_enabled**, **enable_materialized_views**, **cdc_enabled**,
>   **prepared_statements_cache_size_mb**, **back_pressure_strategy**,
>   **concurrent_materialized_view_writes**,
>   **transparent_data_encryption_options**,
>   **thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb**,
>   **slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms**, **hints_flush_period_in_ms**,
>   **max_hints_file_size_in_mb**] from your cassandra.yaml

do not exists in cassandra 2.2.12. Consider editing the cassandra.yaml provided in 2.2.12, or probably better, consider upgrading to the latest recommended version, 3.11.3 as of today.